# How to build a NetChain by the information of ClassifierFunction?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

NetChain provides a method **NetExtract**.
I want to see how `standClassify = Classify[trainingData, Method -> "NeuralNetwork"]` works,beacause it has a better accuracy.
I cann't find a method to do a such thing like **NetExtract**.
I ran`Save["standClassify ", standClassify ]`,and got all information 

`standClassify = ClassifierFunction[
     <|"Basic" -> ....|>]`
,deleted `ClassifierFunction[]`,ran `Get["standClassify"]`.
Then ran `standClassify[["Models"]]`.
I still cann't understand the structure.
`Dimensions /@ \
(standClassify[["Models"]][[1]][["NeuralNetwork"]][["Weights"]])`

> {{972, 324}, {972, 972}, {10, 972}}

My input Dimension is 784,  [image]

### Maybe other good solution to get those information.

`reduce = DimensionReduction[Keys[trainingData], 324]` to get **DimensionReducerFunction**
Then transform input `transform[data_] := 
  Replace[#, 
     RuleDelayed[image_ -> label_, reduce[image] -> label]] & /@ data;`
Train `standClassify = 
 NetTrain[lineNet, trainingData // transform, MaxTrainingRounds -> 3, 
  TargetDevice -> "GPU"]`.

This didn't work well,classifier-accuracy is **0.8676**.
Accuracy can be **0.9379** if I use `Classify`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For example, we have data:

```
SeedRandom[0];
n = 1000;
X = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 10}];
Y = RandomInteger[1, n];
```

```
c = Classify[X -> Y, Method -> "NeuralNetwork"]
```

Let's see the options:

```
Options[c]
```

We can see neuron types:
[image]

Let's reconstruct this network:

```
net = NetChain[
  {LinearLayer[30], Ramp, LinearLayer[30], Ramp, 2, SoftmaxLayer[]},
  "Input" -> 10,
  "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {0, 1}}]
  ]
```

[image]

But weights are uninitialized. Let's initialize them with `NetReplacePart`. This is the new function in V11.1. As I see you are using V11.0. But you can experiment with V11.1 in the [Wolfram Open Cloud](https://www.open.wolframcloud.com/) for free.

```
weights = Options[c][[1]]["Models"][[1]]["NeuralNetwork"]["Weights"];
biases = Options[c][[1]]["Models"][[1]]["NeuralNetwork"]["Biases"];

net = NetReplacePart[net,
  {
   {1, "Weights"} -> weights[[1]],
   {1, "Biases"} -> biases[[1]],
   {3, "Weights"} -> weights[[2]],
   {3, "Biases"} -> biases[[2]],
   {5, "Weights"} -> weights[[3]],
   {5, "Biases"} -> biases[[3]]
   }
  ]
```

Let's compare our classifiers:

```
ClassifierMeasurements[c, X -> Y, "ConfusionMatrixPlot"]
```

[image]

In V11.1 network can be converted into a `ClassifierFunction`.

```
ClassifierMeasurements[Classify[net], Standardize[X] -> Y, "ConfusionMatrixPlot"]
```

[image]

Result is the same!

**Additional links:**

1. Wolfram Open Cloud: https://www.open.wolframcloud.com
2. How to change weights of a neural network: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/141291/23402
3. "Is it possible to convert the result of NetTrain to a PredictorFunction?": https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140095/23402

Comment: In v12.2, the Options[c] outputs an empty list, may I ask what should I do?

Comment: Hello @Charmbracelet! Try `c[[1]]`.

Comment: Thanks, it works!